# How can I create a signal quality plugin in Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, signal-strength

I've tried to use some answers here to create a Cordova plugin for Signal Quality (it can be in dBm or 0-4 level), but nothing worked.

Those with the PhoneStateListener did not work as well, as in Cordova you need to create this type of class:

> ```
> public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
>     if (action.equals("signal")){
> ```

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I've read the Android Developers page related to this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html

But nothing came up to me. I'm getting really frustrated with this plugin, as it's the last one, once it's finished, the project is done too.

Thanks,
MYS77

**EDIT 2**

I've already used these codes:

1:

> ```
> CellInfo allCellInfo = (CellInfo) tm.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
>               CellSignalStrength cellSignalStrength = ((CellInfoGsm) allCellInfo).getCellSignalStrength();
>               level = cellSignalStrength.getLevel();
> ```

2:

> ```
> List<NeighboringCellInfo> neighbors = tm.getNeighboringCellInfo();
>           for (NeighboringCellInfo n : neighbors) {
>               if (n.getRssi() != NeighboringCellInfo.UNKNOWN_RSSI) {
>                   dbm = n.getRssi();
>               }
> ```

3:

> ```
> TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
> MyPhoneStateListener MyListener;
>
>   @Override
>   public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
>     boolean result = false;
>     String level = "";
>     if (action.equals("signal")){
>         try{
>             tm.listen(MyListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
>             callbackContext.success("Hey!");
>             level = MyListener.getStrength();
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex) {
>             callbackContext.error("ERROR");
>         }
>         finally{
>             if (level != "") {
>                 callbackContext.success("Signal Strength = "+level);
>             }
>             else{
>                 callbackContext.success("Could not retrieve signal quality.");
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     return result;
>   }
> }
>
> class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener{
>   String gsmStrength = "";
>
>   @Override
>   public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
>     super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
>     gsmStrength = String.valueOf(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength()* 2 - 113);           
> }
> public String getStrength() {
>     return gsmStrength;
> }
> ```

They do not generate any errors but when I test on my Xperia M2 Aqua it keeps sending "Invalid action" as a response.

Comment: No way to do this? I'm really in need of some help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind again, as nobody is helping... I found a way to do this in GSM network:

**EDIT 2**:
Deleted my previous answers, as this code is working for both Samsung and non-Samsung devices.

> ```
> public string signalStrength(){
>  TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
>    int dBmlevel = 0;
>    int asulevel = 0;
>    String res = "";
>             try {
>                 List<CellInfo> cellInfoList = tm.getAllCellInfo();
>                 //Checking if list values are not null
>                 if (cellInfoList != null) {
>                     for (final CellInfo info : cellInfoList) {
>                         if (info instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
>                             //GSM Network
>                             CellSignalStrengthGsm cellSignalStrength = ((CellInfoGsm)info).getCellSignalStrength();
>                             dBmlevel = cellSignalStrength.getDbm();
>                             asulevel = cellSignalStrength.getAsuLevel();
>                         }
>                         else if (info instanceof CellInfoCdma) {
>                             //CDMA Network
>                             CellSignalStrengthCdma cellSignalStrength = ((CellInfoCdma)info).getCellSignalStrength();
>                             dBmlevel = cellSignalStrength.getDbm();
>                             asulevel = cellSignalStrength.getAsuLevel();
>                         }
>                         else if (info instanceof CellInfoLte) {
>                             //LTE Network
>                             CellSignalStrengthLte cellSignalStrength = ((CellInfoLte)info).getCellSignalStrength();
>                             dBmlevel = cellSignalStrength.getDbm();
>                             asulevel = cellSignalStrength.getAsuLevel();
>                         }
>                         else if  (info instanceof CellInfoWcdma) {
>                             //WCDMA Network
>                             CellSignalStrengthWcdma cellSignalStrength = ((CellInfoWcdma)info).getCellSignalStrength();
>                             dBmlevel = cellSignalStrength.getDbm();
>                             asulevel = cellSignalStrength.getAsuLevel();
>                         }
>                         else{
>                             res = "Unknown type of cell signal.";
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>                 else{
>                     //Mostly for Samsung devices, after checking if the list is indeed empty.
>                     MyListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
>                     tm.listen(MyListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
>                     int cc = 0;
>                     while ( signalLevel == -1){
>                         Thread.sleep(200);
>                         if (cc++ >= 5)
>                         {
>                             break;
>                         }
>                     }
>                     asulevel = signalLevel;
>                     dBmlevel = -113 + 2 * asulevel;
>                     tm.listen(MyListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
>                     signalLevel = -1;
>                 }
>                 result = true;
>             }
>             catch (Exception ex){
>                 res = "Failed to retrieve signal strength";
>             }
>             finally{
>                 res = "Signal strength: " + dBmlevel + " dBm, "+ asulevel + " asu";
>             }
>      return res;
>   }
> ```